# finding substring from a main string

Tags: c, string, visual-studio

My assignment is to find a substring from main string and return the pointer to the first character of the substring that is in mainstring and it needs to stop searching after `"?"` and the code has to be done without `string.h` . My code to me is working perfectly but the automatic checker says otherwise, checker says this

`test_source.c:195:F:test_es_strstr:test_es_strstr:0: [07_altstring.d] Wrong return value with string "Foobarbaz?asd:w" and substring "baz?": Got 0x72, expected 0x7ffeb8b8a306`

So the checker says that my pointer isn't in the right place.. but for me it is, need help.

My code =

```
const char *es_strstr(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (str1[j] != '?')    ///function has to stop the search to 
                             /// a question mark
    {
        if (*str1 == str2[i])    ///comparing main string first character
                                /// to substring first character
        {
            i++;
            ++str1;
            if (*str1 == str2[i])   ///if first ones are match then look
                                    /// for the next character matching
            {
                i++;
                ++str1;
                if (*str1 == str2[i])  /// finally if 2nd is match then 3rd
                {
                    --str1;
                    --str1;
                    printf("%c\n", *str1);
                    return *str1;
                }

            }
        }
        j++;
        i = 0;
        ++str1;
    }
    return NULL;           ///if nothing matches need to return NULL

int main(void) {
    char *main = "Foobarbaz?asd:w";
    char *sub = "baz?";
    es_strstr(main, sub);
    }
```

Comment: `const char *es_strstr` and `return *str`. Something is not right!

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, read them and treat them as errors

Comment: ".. but for me it is" How could you know? You don't do anything with the return value of your function. If you tried to print it, you would think different.

Comment: I did print it in main and in the function itself and they were a match but anyways I got it working already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should return pointer, i.e.

```
return str1;
```

instead of

```
return *str1;
```

*str means character pointed by str1